# AWS Elastic Container Registry Push commands for my-app not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, push

Hi every nerds in the planet...

WHY IS AWS SO COMPLICATED AND aaaaaah
it is getting me crazy , I am trying to push my-app that I built throw docker build and pushing it to the aws
but the thing is that needed to Retrieve an authentication token and authenticate your Docker client to your registry.
Use AWS Tools for PowerShell:
`(Get-ECRLoginCommand).Password | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $SOMETHING.dkr.ecr.$REGION.amazonaws.com`

that command never worked
I downloaded the CLI aws to my computer , and here is the version :
`C:\Users\Milad>aws --version aws-cli/2.14.6 Python/3.11.6 Windows/10 exe/AMD64 prompt/off`

anyone knows what to do next ?!,

Thanks in advance

I am trying to get this command to work :
`(Get-ECRLoginCommand).Password | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $SOMETHING.dkr.ecr.$REGION.amazonaws.com`

Comment: Please explain `that command never worked`. What happens / what error do you see. You will probably also get more useful replies if you trim some of the words that aren't really describing the problem, what you've tried, what you're seeing